# HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7, phpmyadmin, json

Iam providing datas using json to an ios app using php. But while running the code in browser, it is showing Server error. If there is no values in the database, it shows `{"posts":null}`   as provided in the code. But the problem occurs if there is value in the database. It shows the error 
 `Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://path to the server file/php/categoryitemlisting.php?category=11. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.`
This error is occuring only for this php file. Using the other files, I am able to transfer data.

My connection.php file :

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
mysql_select_db('cotton',$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');
?>
```

Categoryitemlisting.php

```
 <?php

   require('connection.php');
   $item = array()       ;

   /* connect to the db */
      if(isset($_REQUEST['category']))
      {
            $k=$_REQUEST['category'];
        /* grab the posts from the db */
             // $k=11;
            $catid = mysql_query("SELECT entity_id FROM  field_data_field_cat WHERE field_cat_tid= $k");
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($catid))
           {

               $category[] = $r['entity_id'];   
               foreach ( $category as $cat );
              {

                 $data= mysql_query("SELECT field_data_field_name.entity_id, field_data_field_name.field_name_value, file_managed.uri, field_data_field_sec.field_sec_tid FROM file_managed INNER JOIN ( field_data_field_thumb, field_data_field_name, field_data_field_sec ) ON ( file_managed.fid = field_data_field_thumb.field_thumb_fid AND field_data_field_name.entity_id = field_data_field_thumb.entity_id AND field_data_field_thumb.entity_id = field_data_field_sec.entity_id ) WHERE field_data_field_name.entity_id = $cat");  

               $items = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
               $item[]= $items;
              }
            }
                $re="public:\/\/";
                $list = json_encode(array('posts'=>$item));
            $list = str_replace( $re, "http://localhost/sites/default/files/" ,$list);
                echo $list;

             @mysql_close($link);

      }

      else
      {
      echo "connection failed";
      }
?>
```

How can I get the values by fixing this error? I dont think so it is the problem of server. If there is any other mistakes in the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last pointed out the issue....

there was a space in   `$k=$_REQUEST[' category'];` in the server code. That caused the error .

Answer (score 0):

Look into yout php.ini and set:

`display_errors = on`
`error_reporting = E_ALL`

If display_error is off and you have any type of problem with your code (e.g.: parse error) your response will be a 500 status page.

Comment: Both the display_errors and error_reporting are same in my php.ini. But the error remains the same